# iPhone HTTP Streaming .m3u8 and .ts files - how to create using ffmpeg

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding

I'm trying to get apple-validated http media streams using ffmpeg and am getting errors. Here are some error examples:

> WARNING: Playlist Content-Type is 'application/x-mpegurl', but should
>   be one of 'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl', 'audio/x-mpegurl' or
>   'audio/mpegurl'.
>
> WARNING: 258 samples (88.966 %) do not have timestamps in track 256
>   (avc1).   4:    us2-1.ts
>           ~~~~~~~~
>
> WARNING: Media segment duration outside of expected duration by 47.733
>   % (5.23 vs. 10.00 seconds, limit is 20 %).  40:    us2-19.ts
>           ~~~~~~~~~

```
Average segment duration: 10.16 seconds
Average segment bitrate: 320.12 kbit/s
Average segment structural overhead: 175.89 kbit/s (54.94 %)

Video codec: avc1
Video resolution: 320x320 pixels
Video frame rate: 29.72, 29.78, 29.82, 30.00, 29.64 fps
Average video bitrate: 100.66 kbit/s
H.264 profile: Baseline
H.264 level: 3.0

Audio codec: aac 
Audio sample rate: 48000 Hz
Average audio bitrate: 43.57 kbit/s
```

---

Here is the end file I've been submitting: http://files.chesscomfiles.com/images_users/using/us2.m3u8

Here is the file I used to create this: http://files.chesscomfiles.com/images_users/using/using-computers-1.mp4

I've tried these commands, among others:

> ffmpeg -i using-computers-1.mp4 -f mpegts -acodec libfaac -ar 48000
>   -ab 64k -s 320x320 -vcodec libx264 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -b 96k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 2 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 96k -bufsize 96k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -g 30 -async 2 us2.ts
>
> ffmpeg -i using-computers-1.mp4 -f mpegts -acodec libfaac -ar 48000
>   -ab 64k -s 320x320 -vcodec libx264 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -b 96k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 96k -bufsize 96k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -g 30 -async 2 us1.ts
>
> ffmpeg -i using-computers-1.mp4 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mpegts output.ts

If someone can help me figure out what ffmpeg commands I should be running I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the first warning:

> WARNING: Playlist Content-Type is
>   'application/x-mpegurl', but should be
>   one of
>   'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl',
>   'audio/x-mpegurl' or 'audio/mpegurl'.

It could be from the server setup. Follow the instructions from Step 4 of this [Ion Cannon post](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/):

> Prepare the HTTP server Upload a set
>   of files that represent the stream and
>   a stream definition file (ts and
>   m3u8). Those files can be uploaded to
>   a web server at this point but there
>   is another important step to take that
>   ensures they will be download
>   correctly and that is setting up mime
>   types. There are two mime types that
>   are important for the streaming
>   content:
>
> .m3u8 application/x-mpegURL
>
> .ts video/MP2T
>
> If you are using Apache you
>   would want to add the following to
>   your httpd.conf file:
>
> AddType application/x-mpegURL .m3u8
>
> AddType video/MP2T .ts
>
> If you are
>   using lighttpd you would want to put
>   this in your configuration file (if
>   you have other mime types defined make
>   sure you just add these and don't set
>   them):
>
> mimetype.assign = ( ".m3u8" =>
>   "application/x-mpegURL", ".ts" =>
>   "video/MP2T" )

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the third warning:

> WARNING: Media segment duration
>   outside of expected duration by 47.733
>   % (5.23 vs. 10.00 seconds, limit is 20
>   %). 40: us2-19.ts ~~~~~~~~~

This usually happens if a segment is a different duration than how the duration listed for that segment in the playlist (m3u8). For example, the below playlist has one segment and is listed by the playlist to be 10 seconds. If the actual duration of this segment is different by too much (more than 20%), than the validator will complain.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:10, 
med0.ts 
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Usually the last segment in a playlist will differ a bit from the target, and this warning can be ignored.

And, as a general rule these "WARNING" messages can be ignored, but "ERROR" messages need to be taken seriously.

However, the second warning looks more serious, and could possibly lead to a rejection from Apple. It could be your segmenter commands (are you using mediastreamsegmenter?).

Also, I'm not using "-vbsf h264_mp4toannexb". And, I'm using "-async 50".

Btw, the link to your playlist is invalid.