# Reducing the initial delay when playing remote video content

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, buffer

Hi using MPMoviePlayerController to stream video into the app. However, it takes a long time to load and I want to be able to pre-buffer the video. Any suggestions?

Comment: Anything below 8 seconds can be considered normal - are you within that range? To cut those 8 seconds short, check my answer on point 1. - in short; prepare to play before the user actually hits the play button.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use
   `[MPMoviePlayerControllerInstance prepareToPlay]`
   as soon as you know that the user
   might start playback of a movie. You
   might also want set
   `MPMoviePlayeController.autoPlay` to
   something that fits best, depending
   on your application.

   From [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback);

   > This method is called
   >   automatically when you call the play
   >   method. Calling it before you call
   >   play gives the receiver a chance to
   >   prepare items sooner and may result in
   >   decreased latency when starting
   >   playback. However, calling this method
   >   may also interrupt any active audio
   >   sessions.
2. Make sure your HTTP stream contains
   a low bandwidth alternative using
   less than 64Kbps (audio and video combined). Note that the
   `MPMoviePlayerController` usually
   starts buffering the low rate
   playback index profile before
   raising the bar and attempting to
   load higher bandwidth profiles. It
   will be prepared to play once it has
   a few seconds worth of movie data.
3. Use the
   `MPMoviePlayerController.movieSourceType`
   property when initializing your
   player to cut down the media
   recognition delay.

   From the [MPMoviePlayerController
   Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

   > The default value of this property is
   >   MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown. This
   >   property provides a clue to the
   >   playback system as to how it should
   >   download and buffer the movie content.
   >   If you know the source type of the
   >   movie, setting the value of this
   >   property before playback begins can
   >   improve the load times for the movie
   >   content. If you do not set the source
   >   type explicitly before playback, the
   >   movie player controller must gather
   >   this information, which might delay
   >   playback.

Comment: Thanks i have tried that and its not really improved it. Also would i need to use     //playerViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

Comment: Ive also notice everytime i use player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

Comment: it just states loading and does not load the video...this is very frustrating as all i would like to do is present the standard video loader to the user whilst its buffering...any further suggestions. Also as I am fairly new to xcode am i using the right class to "stream" video...

Comment: Are you actually using an HTTP-Stream? It sounds to me as if you were using progressive download instead. Is the file-extension m3u8 or mp4?

Comment: Good point to suggest the mediatype to the player, adding that to my list of suggestions.

Comment: hi using http-stream now. I am nearly up and running but now getting a few errors when using the validating tool:

Comment: WARNING: Playlist Content-Type is 'text/plain', but should be one of 'application/x-mpegurl', 'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl', 'audio/x-mpegurl' or 'audio/mpegurl'.

Comment: That is not an error but a warning and can usually be ignored.

Comment: i am assuming the manifest is what i point to in my app which will detect the bandwidth, thanks for your help so far

Comment: You should search right here on SO for help on that matter. When getting stuck, try posting a new question. If my answers helped, please upvote and accept. See this for more on creating HTTP-streams compatible with iOS devices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209243/iphone-http-streaming-m3u8-and-ts-files-how-to-create-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Just a small correction since the IDE doesn't recognize: "autoPlay", you should try: 'shouldAutoplay' ;)