# Movie is played with some delay after calling play on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am developing an iPhone application in which I play videos using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Sometimes, some of the videos don't play immediately after I call play on `MPMoviePlayerController`.

I have called prepareToPlay and in the notified method of `MPMediaPlaybackIsPreparedToPlayDidChangeNotification`, I am calling play on `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Could someone help in identifying the problem here?

Thanks,
Laxmilal

Comment: Are the videos local or are they on a server somewhere?

Comment: Videos are local i..e In Resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my answer in a similar thread ([reducing-the-initial-delay-when-playing-remote-video-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549967/reducing-the-initial-delay-when-playing-remote-video-content)) - **Note** this fragment of the solution is valid for both, remote and local video content.

Use the`MPMoviePlayerController.movieSourceType`property when initializing your
  player to cut down the media
  recognition delay.

From the [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The default value of this property is
>   MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown. This
>   property provides a clue to the
>   playback system as to how it should
>   download and buffer the movie content.
>   If you know the source type of the
>   movie, setting the value of this
>   property before playback begins can
>   improve the load times for the movie
>   content. If you do not set the source
>   type explicitly before playback, the
>   movie player controller must gather
>   this information, which might delay
>   playback.