# I want to concatinate 2 videos through mpmovie player

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

Currently i am running the second video in movie End notification method. But delay between two movies are too much.i dont want that delay.how can i show that these two movies are acyually one movie?

Answer (score 0):

You will always have a small gap between those two movies. You can however reduce the recognition / identification delay by presetting the exact type of content you will be playing.

For further hints on this subject, see my answer to this question:
[reducing-the-initial-delay-when-playing-remote-video-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549967/reducing-the-initial-delay-when-playing-remote-video-content)